# Hotkey для переключение на терминал в CentOS 7 GNOME Shell

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, gnome

Есть ли в CentOS 7 возможность поставить hotkey для переключение на открытое окно терминала и при следующем нажатии его сворачивать?

Answer (score 0):

Вот похоже почти то, что нужно - https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/442/drop-down-terminal/

Ну или [классика](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/best-drop-down-terminal-apps-linux/)

1. Guake
2. Yakuake
3. Qterminal
4. Tilda